# How to run java agent on Corda node by configuring jvm args in gradle build?

Tags: jvm, build.gradle, corda

I am trying to run a JavaAgent that monitors the code execution on one or multiple Corda nodes so I can track coverage of my functional tests when they are running.

The [Corda docs](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.5/operations/deployment/running-a-node.html) say you can add JVM args by adding this to my node spec:

```
custom = {
   jvmArgs: [ "-javaAgent:/Path/To/Agent/jacoco-agent.jar=config-file=/Path/To/Agent/jacoco-agent.config",  "-Xmx1G", "-XX:+UseG1GC" ]
}
```

It seems that I have to add this to each nodes config file but is there a way to add this to all nodes through the build.gradle for example so the agent starts when the node start.

Answer (score 2):

you can edit the `node.conf` of the generated nodes from the `node` or `nodeDefaults` section of the `deployNodes` task (or any task of type `net.corda.plugins.Cordform`) in the `build.gradle`, so you can simply use

```
node {
    extraConfig = ['custom.jvmArgs': ["-Xmx1G", "-XX:+UseG1GC"]]
}
```

note that in Groovy, both lists and dictionaries use square bracket syntax
e.g.

```
["key" : "value", "key2" : true, "key3" : 42]
```

Comment: Thanks! I manage to add this and build everything but my agent doesn't get attached. There is no mention of it in the logs. If I try exactly the same but with your arguments above, I see them under [main] internal.Node. - CommandLine Args: "Xmx1G" -XX:+UseG1GC in the logs.

It is like it ignore if I use -javaagent argument. Got any suggestion how to debug that?

Comment: Does it break if you spell it wrong? Like `-jvaagent`?

Comment: It does. 

Unrecognized option: -jvaagent:

Comment: How are you running your tests? Do you manually start up your nodes?

Comment: I don't run any tests now. I just run deployNodes and runnodes, then I check the /logs folder to see if the javaagent was picked up. The path to my agent-jar is the absolut path on the system. Should it maybe be relative to the project folder?

Comment: The absolute path should be fine, note that it breaks if you pass a wrong path (a path to a non existing jar file). If it doesn't break it means that your agent is likely to be booted correctly

Comment: When I tried manually starting the node and add the -javaagent manually in the generated run-command, it did actually show up in the logs where I would expect it to do.  This leads me to think that there are some issues with the run script to actually add the jvmArgs to the generated run-command. Could there be an issue there perhaps?